# How to add and align button at center below the graph with controller file in javafx?

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Am trying to add button and align it below the graph at the center the graph is added as node inside the pane, I want to align a button to print the scene by clicking the button below, how to do that can you please help me out. Thank you in advance

```
    Stage stage = new Stage();


    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();        

       ScatterChart<Number,Number> sc = new ScatterChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);


         sc.setTitle("ScatterPlot");
         XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();  
        for(int j=0;j<collectionValue.get(0).size();j++)
        {
            xAxis.setLabel(al1.get(0).toString());                
             yAxis.setLabel(al1.get(1).toString());
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(collectionValue.get(0).get(j),collectionValue.get(1).get(j) ));  
       }
        sc.getData().add(series1);
        System.out.println("Max num in the arraylist Collection.get(0) is: " + Collections.max(collectionValue.get(0)));
        System.out.println("Max num in the arraylist Collection.get(1) is: " + Collections.max(collectionValue.get(1)));
        System.out.println("Min num in the arraylist Collection.get(0) is: " + Collections.min(collectionValue.get(0)));
        System.out.println("Min num in the arraylist Collection.get(1) is: " + Collections.min(collectionValue.get(1)));



        regValue1.add(regression(collectionValue.get(0),collectionValue.get(1)));

        System.out.println("RegValue outside regression: " + regValue1);


        LineChart<Number,Number> lc = new LineChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();

        xfirst = (double)regValue1.get(0).get(0) + (double)regValue1.get(0).get(1)*(float)Collections.min(collectionValue.get(0));
        xsecond = (double)regValue1.get(0).get(0)+(double)regValue1.get(0).get(1)*(float)Collections.max(collectionValue.get(0));

        final XYChart.Data<Object, Object> data = new XYChart.Data<>((float)Collections.min(collectionValue.get(0)),xfirst);
        data.setNode(new HoveredThresholdNodea((float)Collections.min(collectionValue.get(0)),xfirst));

        final XYChart.Data<Object, Object> data1 = new XYChart.Data<>((float)Collections.max(collectionValue.get(0)),xsecond);
        data1.setNode(new HoveredThresholdNodea((float)Collections.max(collectionValue.get(0)),xsecond));


        series2.getData().add(data);
        series2.getData().add(data1);        

        System.out.println(regValue1.get(0).get(1));
        System.out.println(regValue1.get(0).get(0));
        System.out.println("xfirst: " + xfirst);
        System.out.println("xsecond" + xsecond);

        lc.getData().add(series2);
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        JFXButton btn = new JFXButton();
        pane.getChildren().add(sc);         
        pane.getChildren().add(lc);
        pane.getChildren().add(btn);
       lc.prefHeightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().subtract(50));
       lc.prefWidthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
       sc.prefHeightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().subtract(50));
       sc.prefWidthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());


        lc.setOpacity(0.5);
        lc.autosize();


        Scene scene  = new Scene(pane, 600, 500);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
}
```

This is the graph:

[image: You can see the image of the graph, below which I want to add one button and align it to center]

Comment: Make your root pane a VBox. Add a StackPane to your VBox and then add your graph to the StackPane. Add another StackPane to your VBox and then add your button.

Comment: can you please show me how ? Just a small hint

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample app.

> The VBox is used to stack the nodes over each other. The StackPane automatically centers nodes contained within it.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LineChartSample extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        //populating the series with data
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));


        StackPane spLineChart = new StackPane();
        spLineChart.getChildren().add(lineChart);

        Button button = new Button("Click Me!");
        button.setOnMouseClicked((event)->{
            System.out.println("You just clicked me");
        });
        StackPane spButton = new StackPane();
        spButton.getChildren().add(button);

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        VBox.setVgrow(spLineChart, Priority.ALWAYS);//Make line chart always grow vertically
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(spLineChart, spButton);



        Scene scene  = new Scene(vbox,800,600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);       

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> Scene structure:

```
root: - VBox
          - StackPane
              -LineChart
          - StackPane
              -Button
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't set alignment for Pane, you have to change containers.

If the window is non-resizeable you could add a region to the Pane, experiment by altering its dimensions and position added to Pane.

```
Region shiftRight = new Region();
shiftRight.setMinWidth(112);
```